# Key logger wont record key strokes without console

Tags: c++, logging, hwnd, keylogger, findwindow

I created a small basic key logger in C++. For some reason when I compile and run the program with the console displayed, it will record every key stroke I make in whatever program I am using such as a browser and store it in a text file. However when I make it so that it WON'T display a console window, it will not record anything and it's just a process in the background doing nothing. Here is the link to my code: http://pastebin.com/4wqQyLJ9
The function that is giving me trouble with hiding the console, is the Stealth() function. Any suggestions, tips or hints will be helpful.

Comment: What's the point of `Stealth()` anyway? If you run as a console program you already have a console, so do just `ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE)`; if you run as a GUI... don't create the console at all.

Comment: Please reduce your code to a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) and include the code in your question, **not** a link to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this function , it works for me pretty well.

```
  ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);
```

Comment: This also doesn't work for me. You may have to make a logger more sophisticated and respond to events from the OS. This would be the only reliable way to my knowledge. Dealing with Win32 or POSIX is a pain but it does work.

Comment: Change `int main()` to `int __stdcall WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)` instead. Then remove the `ShowWindow`.. This will make the console invisible.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hiding the window after the program starts, I solved this by not
having a window to begin with. Compile with `-mwindows` and a window is not
created when the program starts.

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/suede)

Answer (score 0):

I would consider a Windows Service for this kind of thing if you don't need UI.  Also using GetAsyncKeyState can be more stealthy if required.  This C++ source might be of use...

[Windows Service Keylogger](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/41669-windows-service-keylogger/)